# Auto-resize UIView to fit iPhone 5 screen while maintaining proportion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5, autoresize

My `StoryBoard` is configured for iPhone4 resolution, and when running on iPhone 5 I'd like a UIView to get bigger (both height&width).

The problem right now is that the view is **only getting higher and not wider**. What should be the auto-resize configuration in order to achieve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using (shudder) Auto Layout?

Comment: In needs to work on iOS5 also, so Auto-Layout is not an option.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like you'd need to use a subclass and code then. Just a minute...

Comment: Use the spring and struts properly and the view will be properly resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use a subclass of `UIView` with the `setFrame:` method overridden to catch frame changes.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.size.width = frame.size.height; // Make the *width* always equal to the *height*. Logic could go here, etc.
    [super setFrame:frame]
}
```

Comment: The height and width don't necessarily need to be the same. They just need to grow proportionally.

Comment: My initial state (200x200) is just an example, the initial height&width can be anything.

Comment: Then you could add logic there that says something like that the width always needs to be one third of the height, etc.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Any other (better) suggestions are still welcome though.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference the height of the screen and use some padding values to set your view frame. Below is code to set the frame of a UIView called `yourShapeView`:

```
// Get the frame of the screen
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

// Set padding from the top and bottom of the shape
CGFloat verticalPadding = 40.0f;
CGFloat horizontalPadding = 20.0f;

// Get the height/width values
CGFloat height = screenFrame.size.height - (verticalPadding * 2);
CGFloat width = screenFrame.size.width - (horizontalPadding * 2);

// Set the size of your shape based on the height and padding
yourShapeView.frame = CGRectMake(horizontalPadding, verticalPadding, width, height);
```